# Disappearing UISearchController in a TableViewController that is in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, search, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uisearchbar

I have made a UITableView Controller with a UISearchBar as the Table's header.

I have then embedded this View Controller into a UINavigationController, as the root view controller.

Now, when I tap on the Search Bar, the SearchBar seems to disappears and displays a white screen. The keyboard appears, but there is no Search Bar.
The Table View can scroll, but the search bar has simply vanished.

When I implement this UITableViewController *without* the Navigation Controller, it works perfectly. But something about the Navigation Controller is borking everything up.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue that was sometimes happening, especially with table view of small number of rows (less than 50).
It appears the searchBar is removed from the view hierarchy, precisely from the container view that is a child of the UISearchControllerView.

I've found a workaround to manually add back the searchbar as a subview of the UISearchControllerView container child. This is implemented in the delegate function (from UISearchControllerDelegate) didPresentSearchController:

```
func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.superview == nil {
        for searchCtrlChildView in searchController.view.subviews {
            if searchCtrlChildView.frame.origin == CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) { //Discriminate if by chance there was more than one subview
                searchCtrlChildView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also filed a radar to Apple on this as it is not fixed in iOS 8.4

Comment: It's already iOS 9.3 and it's still not fixed by Apple. But thanks for the fix @Damien. In my case, it doesn't disappear on first activation coz I got this `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;`. However, after typing some text in the `textField` then tapping the Cancel button to de-active the controller, activating it again will somehow cause the `searchBar` to de-attach itself.

Answer (score 0):

### Check the way I had my searchBar it in viewDidLoad

*I have my viewController embedded  in NavigationController too*

**My code (hope it helps) :**

```
class myTableViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        return controller
    })()
```